# Error when creating new Rails project: Unable to satisfy the following requirements: activesupport (= 7.0.4.3), activesupport (>= 4.2.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Here are my configuration

```
Mac M1
```

```
❯ gem env version      
3.4.10
```

```
❯ ruby --version
ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [arm64-darwin22]
```

```
❯ rails --version
7.0.4.3
```

When I try to create a new rails project this the error I'm getting

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/universal-darwin22/rbconfig.rb:21: warning: Insecure world writable dir /opt/homebrew in PATH, mode 040777
Ignoring racc-1.6.2 because its extensions are not built. Try: gem pristine racc --version 1.6.2
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/conflict.rb:47:in `conflicting_dependencies': undefined method `request' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb:61:in `conflicting_dependencies'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/exceptions.rb:55:in `initialize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:193:in `exception'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:193:in `raise'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:193:in `rescue in resolve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:191:in `resolve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:411:in `resolve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:423:in `resolve_current'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:228:in `finish_resolve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `synchronize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /Users/niki/.gem/ruby/2.6.10/bin/rails:25:in `<main>'
/Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state': Unable to satisfy the following requirements: (Gem::Resolver::Molinillo::VersionConflict)

- `activesupport (= 7.0.4.3)` required by `user-specified dependency`
- `activesupport (>= 4.2.0)` required by `rails-dom-testing-2.0.3`
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:682:in `attempt_to_activate'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:254:in `process_topmost_state'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver/molinillo/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/resolver.rb:190:in `resolve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:411:in `resolve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:423:in `resolve_current'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:228:in `finish_resolve'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:285:in `block in activate_bin_path'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `synchronize'
    from /Library/Ruby/Site/2.6.0/rubygems.rb:283:in `activate_bin_path'
    from /Users/niki/.gem/ruby/2.6.10/bin/rails:25:in `<main>'
```

I've tried uninstalling and installing everything on latest version including ruby on brew as well as on rbenv.. Not sure what is going wrong here

Comment: Looks like you're missing ```activesupport```.

Comment: I did `gem install activesupport` still getting the same error. @ewokx

Comment: You need use ruby version manager (choose one from asdf, rbenv, rvm). Now you use system Ruby. It is bad idea

Comment: I'm already using rbenv @mechnicov

Comment: Your log contains system Ruby paths. Therefore it is not rbenv Ruby. You need use rbenv Ruby

Comment: How exactly did you install Ruby 3.2.2 and Rails 7.0.4.3? What command did you run to create the new rails project. What were the exact commands you ran in the console?

Comment: Thanks @mechnicov Now I got the problem, My .zshrc file was having ruby path exported which was creating the problem Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use descriptive titles. "I'm getting an error" is a generic and useless title. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask, specifically **Write a title that summarizes the specific problem**.